# opencv 3 cv2.imshow() displays only window bar

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I just wonder has anybody fixed this issue. I've read all post but found no answers. The problem is: there is a python simple code

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow('test', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    if ret:
        print img.mean()
        cv2.imshow('test', img)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

When I run it I see only a window title bar with no content underneath. But frames keep updating that I can see on terminal with img.mean() printout. Since I set cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL I can grab the window corner and drag it and I see the frame content but at this time frames stop updating. When I release the window corner the window collapses back and frames start updating again.

If I use any other image display functions e.g. dlib.image_window() in my case everything works just fine.

I use opencv 3.2.0-dev compiled from sources with opencv_contrib and python 2.7.13 on MacOS

[image: Screenshot]

### Problem solved

The solution is: in file opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm change

```
@implementation CVView
#if defined(__LP64__)
@synthesize image;
#else // 32-bit Obj-C does not have automatic synthesize
@synthesize image = _image;
#endif
```

to

```
@implementation CVView
@synthesize image = _image;
```

The explanation is [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/160201/video-window-not-loading-frame/?answer=160604#post-id-160604)

@DanMašek, thanks for your comment that made my life easier )

Comment: When you say that you see the frame content, is the frame stuck to some bottom-left corner? That's how it was in another one of the threads with these issues, wondering if it's a common theme. For now, have you tried setting the window size with [`cv2.resizeWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#resizewindow)? Not sure if that will help. You can use it after you create the named window.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, doesn't help either.

Comment: @DanMašek, attached. Thanks, will try to patch window_cocoa.mm and recompile as your link suggests